# How to automatically call with() method on models during query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-8

I have a User Model and Country Model, and Country belongs to User.

I am getting users with country using User model with "with()" method, in different controllers & methods.

```
Users::with('country')->get();
```

in different controllers.
I want

```
Users::get();
```

It should automatically call the with('country') even if I dont call it.

And if I call any other relation like:

```
User::with('role')->get()
```

Now it should get role and country both. Not just role.

How can I achieve this..?

Comment: The documenation has a section on [Eager Loading By Default](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default), would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [default eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default)

You can achieve this by adding a variable to your model called `$with` like so:

```
class User ... {
    protected $with = ['country'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add user's model

$with automatic added your realtionship

```php
protected $with = ['country' , 'add some reation'];
```